# Is it possible to run and create Selenium IDE test cases without Firefox?

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium

I'm using [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) to occasionally test my web applications. However, since Selenium IDE is a plugin for Firefox, and it doesn't exist yet for Firefox 5 (the latest version of Firefox), I cannot run my tests and cannot create new ones.

Is it possible to use Selenium IDE without an older version of Firefox?

**UPDATE:** The currently last version of Selenium IDE works with Firefox 5 (problem solved): http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are asking about the 'recording' feature that the plugin provides. Have a look at the code that it creates (on demand). 
You can also write that code in a text editor or ide of your choice and then run these tests as part of a test suite in the language that you choose (e.g. java).

This solution requires running the browser(s) you want to test on some test machine/server.

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to your question is "yes, if you know how to patch an XPI file".  Firefox plugins declare their minimum and maximum supported Firefox levels in the plugin archive-file, and Selenium takes a conservative approach, only declaring support that has been verified.  FF5 is very new, and hadn't been.

That said, sometimes there are genuine incompatibilities that need to be repaired.  Not often, but sometimes.